# Remove "Figure 1" in text on the right of diagram

Tags: captions, sidecap

How do I remove the label, "Figure 1:" from the caption of the diagram, using the `sidecap` package?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `labelformat=empty` for `\captionsetup` from the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package; here's the code for a particular `SCfigure`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{sidecap}

\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
\rule{4cm}{2cm} % to simulate a figure
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and the code affecting all the `SCfigure` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{sidecap}

\captionsetup[SCfigure]{labelformat=empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
\rule{4cm}{2cm} % to simulate a figure
\caption{A test caption}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

A simpler solution for some particular `SCfigure` would be to use `\caption*` ( from the caption package) instead of `\caption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{sidecap}

\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
\rule{4cm}{2cm} % to simulate a figure
\caption*{A test caption}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```